# Can I get the 'errorThrown' text from a jqXHR object in the complete callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqxhr

The error callback is defined as:

```
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
```

The complete callback is defined as:

```
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
```

I'd like to be able to get the `errorThrown` property from within my `complete` callback. Is it available as part of the jqXHR object?

`complete` is called after `error` but I'd like to avoid some sort of hack that saves the `errorThrown` value so it can be used in `complete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could attach the value to the jqXHR object in the error callback, so long as jQuery passes the same object to both callbacks:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    jqXHR.errorThrown = errorThrown;
},
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log(jqXHR.errorThrown);
}
```

fiddle demonstrating the general concept: http://jsfiddle.net/9kQna/